# DEP0600 Error when deploying UWP project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, hex, uwp

After Visual Studio (Community 2015 Update 3) crashed on deploying a UWP project with a bluescreen (Unexpected Store Exception, this has happened before), i can not deploy any projects anymore. I tried with the project VS crashed on, previous versions of that project as well as completely empty new projects.

The error message is the following:

> DEP0600 : The following unexpected error occurred during deployment:
>
> '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

Repairing Visual Studio made no difference.

I can not locate the problem, but assume something was corrupted during the crash. Would a complete reinstall of VS do more than just a repair here? Does this maybe even require more drastic steps?

Thanks,

Reinhold

Comment: See question please, i already did to no effect.

Comment: I would definitely advise you to reinstall Visual Studio completely in case repair didn't help.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it. Reinstalling VS did not have any effect. However, i moved/cleared VS's Projects folder, which fixed the problem. I dont really see why, as the problem (as stated) also appeared on completely empty, new projects not referencing any others, but clearing that folder allowed new Projects to deploy again.

Comment: @Reinhold I am having the same problem. Can you elaborate how did you move/clear Visual Studio's projects folder?

Comment: @PutraKg I just renamed the `Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects` folder so that VS had to generate a new one. You can copy your projects back into it again later. Also, it seems by the two answers submitted since i had the problem that there is not one clear solution to this, but clearing any VS data you can find that is not cleared by an uninstall is the way to go.

Comment: @Reinhold thanks. I've also tried answer by user2820071. Seems to work with a catch. I commented below that answer.

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions and answers, none worked. Forced to re-install Windows to fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Had same exact error and symptoms deploying to local machine after Windows Crash. Repair/Reinstall of VS did not help. Even system restore could not fix the problem.

For me I had to delete `AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio` folder for VS to rebuilt the necessary files.

Comment: This works for me. But beware that any plugins or customization will be lost and need to be reinstall.

Comment: Renaming project folders does not works for my VS, but this works well. You save my hours of reinstalling the whole system. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was able to deploy a blank javascript uwp project after deleting AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio folder and then restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, I uninstalled all my `UWP` applications from All Settings -> Apps & features. it solved my problem
I just uninstalled `UWP` applications that I( myself) deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Deploy has passed after renamed all project folders.

1. Rename all project folders.
2. Create a new uwp project. Try to run it.
3. Move old projects from the renamed project folders to created by VS with trying run the uwp project after each time.

But projects with DEP0600 error I recreated and moved all files back into new project.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an older thread - I encountered this just today with a UWP project/solution, I was getting the above deployment error in Dev. 
I R-click/uninstalled the existing package from the Start Menu and was good to go. Perhaps the package was in an unrecoverable or corrupted state.

Answer (score 0):

While working on a UWP app for Raspberry Pi 2 I experienced a similar DEP0600 error. Things like restarting Visual Studio or removing temp files didn't work.

It was only after I simply rebooted my Pi I was able to deploy again

Answer (score 0):

Just moving the "Projects" folder from Documents\Visual Studio 2015 to some other place solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error deploying to an xbox - uninstalling the app from dev home on the xbox dashboard fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a more precise solution. I deleted `AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_83b4e368\Designer\`
Replace the version folder with your version of visual studio.