# DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character

Tags: deployment, uwp, visual-studio-2017

MS VS2017. Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

**Edit Begin**

- Solution may be near.  Please hold on suggestions for one day.  In
  response to the comment below. I have renamed original VS2017
  Projects Folder as an archive. MSVS2017 creates a new one, perhaps with no     damages. This is beginning to help the problem.  Blank
  Projects now can be deployed.  Moving the original solution folder
  back in failed.  I am trying to execute file triage to get the
  application running again.  This project is relatively small.  Thus
  the cut and paste solution is being attempted.

**Edit End**

Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1. [0x80131940]

An application was running fine for days.  Now deployment fails.

What does the error mean?  How can I correct it?  There is no file name provided.

The only idea I have seen vaguely by searching is to reinstall VS2017.  For lack of time I have not done this yet.

Thanks.

I would like to give more context.  But many things were changed before the application was run again. So I do not want to submit superstitious ideas yet. Close and Open VS2017.

VS2017 gives me this error even if I create a new blank UWP application.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: I searched for similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678303/dep0600-error-when-deploying-uwp-project). You could try to delete `AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio` folder for VS to rebuilt the necessary files.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT.  I investigated your first link.  I have not investigated the second folder idea.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Deleting the App from Apps & Features solved the problem for me.

Comment: Right click in start menu => uninstall, but yes it worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Error   DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

```
After deleting AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio folder, and restarting 
Visual Studio, this error disappears, and blank projects will deploy normally.
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled the UWP apps from apps and features worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to right click on the solution and click Properties, selected assembly information and incremented the Assembly Version and File Version and recompiled it. Don't ask me why this worked, I have no idea but it worked for me.

In the error that was flagged up it contained the version number 1.3.3.3 so I just changed it to 1.4.1.1 and it worked.

Comment: use comment section