# Visual Studio 2017 project needs to be deployed before it can be started

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to run my UWP app on my local machine and all was going well until Windows crashed.  After that I started getting the error message:

> The Project ### needs to be deployed before it can be started

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have uninstalled VS and reinstalled it and created new projects but I'm getting the same issue every time.  Both the Debug and Deploy boxes are ticked in Configuration Manager for Debug ans x64.  I have seen a few different answers for this but none have worked so far.

This in turn leads to the error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1. [0x80131940]   App3

Every new app I create does exactly the same thing

Comment: This in turn leads to the error message:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error  DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1. [0x80131940] App3

Comment: Please add the error message into the question, not just in a comment.

Comment: Can the question be edited?  The comment refers to the 2nd error which I believe is caused by the first error which is in the title of the question.

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question, and if you thin the 2nd error may be useful it would be helpful to have it in the actual question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEP0600: Deployment failed. XmlException - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299582/dep0600-deployment-failed-xmlexception-hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-an-in)

Comment: I tried that fix and have just tried it again but I am still seeing the same error message.  The fact this worked fine until my laptop crashed seems very odd

Answer (score 3):

In my case it helped when I switched the option Any CPU to x64. Then I could normally debug the program, just as in this picture:
[Change CPU type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ61O.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution. I couldn't uninstall anything because I couldn't find it installed anywhere. What I  had to do is make sure the Platform that was selected in the Configuration  Manager of the solution (Right click solution -> Properties) was the same as in the Visual Studio Editor.

Then I saw the checkboxes "Build" and "Deploy" were unchecked. I checked them and it worked again.

[image: Picture showing platforms on the Visual Studio Editor and Configuration Manager]