# Error Disk image malformed while building WinUI 3 c# project

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am attempting to build my first WINUI 3 Hello World app following the process in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app?tabs=desktop-csharp

After following all the steps without error I build and run resulting in a DEP0600 error.

I am using VS 2019 version 16.10.4, C# Windows 10.0.19042 I am also using Project Reunion v 0.8.1

I deleted the AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio files as suggested and now get
I tried your suggestion and now get

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Inner exception: Class not
> registered REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Any suggestions how to get this barebones example to run?

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310813/4708150

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException  Inner exception: Class not registered REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Comment: did you close all instances of VS 2019, and then restart after deleting that folder?

Comment: I did and it showed the first time use message.  I also have confirmed that my developer mode is on in Windows 10.